# Summarize then average every 10 lines from a txt file

Tags: c++, fstream

I have this code for the task mentioned in the title:

The program reads from a 1 columned text file in which the numbers are below each other.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double number;
    double sum = 0;

    ifstream average;
    average.open("average.txt");

    while (average >> number)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + number;

            i++;

            if (i = 9)
            {
                cout << sum / 10 << endl;
            }
         }
    {

    average.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But somehow it doesn't average the numbers just divide all of them by 10.

What might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The order of `while` and `for` seems wrong. You are reading 1 number and using that 10 times in the for loop.

Comment: As I know the `while (average  >> number)` is the same as `while (!average.eof())`...`getline`

Comment: `if (i = 9)` is assignment, not comparison. It's also always true. ` i++;` inside the loop and inside the `for` means you increment it twice per iteration.

Comment: `double sum;` is used before being initialized -> UB.

Comment: edited it @Jarod42

Comment: https://ideone.com/JFSLq1

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice in the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
int i;
while (average.good()) // only while we are good
{
  sum = 0; // you need to clean it
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {   
    average >> number;

    if (!average.good()) break; // if number of lines is not mod10

    sum = sum + number;
    // i++; you already do that in for loop
  }
  if (i)
  {
    cout << sum / i << endl; // only print after each 10 or less
  }
}
```

Or with the single loop:

```
sum = 0;
int i = 0;

while (average >> number) {
  sum = sum + number;
  ++i;

  if (i == 10) {
    cout << sum / i << endl;
    sum = i = 0;
  }
}
if (i) {
  cout << sum / i << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @RetiredNinja typing faster than thinking, of course

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this easily with a `std::deque` since you can easily add and remove numbers when you reach the tenth quota every line.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <deque>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream read("average.txt");

    constexpr unsigned linesToAverage = 10;
    std::deque<double> numbers;
    double currentNumber = 0.0;

    while (read >> currentNumber) {
        if (numbers.size() == linesToAverage) {
            std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), 0.0) / linesToAverage << std::endl;
            numbers.pop_back();
        }

        numbers.push_front(currentNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code shows the averages starting from the first ten numbers.